# How to prevent raise of LostFocus on MouseDown on an control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mouseevent

**The question is pretty simple:** How do I prevent `LostFocus` from getting raised on `MouseDown` on a control that already got focus?

I have the following control (temporary test with all the event bindings):

```html
<Grid Name="gBase" Focusable="True" MouseUp="SetFocus" MouseDown="SetFocus" MouseMove="gBase_MouseMove" PreviewDragEnter="gBase_PreviewDragEnter" LostFocus="gBase_LostFocus" GotFocus="gBase_GotFocus"  Background="DarkRed" Width="500" Height="250" />
```

And the following code behind:

```cs
private void SetFocus(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = sender as Grid;            
    g.Focus();
}

private void gBase_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = sender as Grid;
    g.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;

}

private void gBase_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = sender as Grid;
    g.Background = Brushes.Aquamarine;
}

private void gBase_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        Grid g = sender as Grid;
        g.Focus();
    }
}

private void gBase_PreviewDragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    Grid g = sender as Grid;
    g.Focus();
}
```

The behaviour is almost of that I want to achieve, if I click on the Grid it get focus.

The problem is that if the Grid already got focus it will lose it while I have the mouse button down and not regain it until I release or move. My prefered behaviour would be to prevent that it loses focus in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that the parent ScrollViewer stole focus.

This was solved by using the event `MouseLeftButtonDown` and setting the `MouseButtonEventArgs.Handled` to `true` to prevent further handling of the event.

Working code:

```html
<Grid Name="gBase" Focusable="True" MouseLeftButtonDown="SetFocus" LostFocus="gBase_LostFocus" GotFocus="gBase_GotFocus" Background="DarkRed" MinWidth="500" MinHeight="250" Width="500" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

```cs
private void SetFocus(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = true;

    Grid g = sender as Grid;
    g.Focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use some property or variable to store which control has actually focus. And after MouseDown compare if control already had focus and if so, then don't do code in LostFocus event.

Important is to update storing property, when focus is changed on other control.

Comment: I guess I could build something like that which could work, but if I don't misinterpret you it would require application wide checks. Must be a better way to solve this and keep it in a smaller scope (UserControl in my case).

Comment: I mean, than you have to do only two things: 1) To add storing of actually focused control in SetFocus event and 2) add condition in LostFocus event.

Comment: It does not matter if I store the actual focused element in SetFocus since it will always be the Grid, and the only thing to trigger LostFocus is my Grid. The problem is to decide if it is a valid LostFocus or not.

Comment: One lead to a solution I found was by checking Keyboard.FocusedElement on LostFocus and it was the parent ScrollViewer.